# Add prefix to localhost base url in Office add-in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I am developing an MS Office addin in React JS. I want to change the base url of my app, by adding prefix to it. Now my default app run on "http://localhost:3000/taskpane.html", but I want to run it on "http://localhost:3000/plan/taskpane.html", as I have to run two app on same domain with different prefixes.

I have tried different solutions but none of them worked for me. I also tried "homepage" in package.json but still failed. Below is the default folder structure, create by yeoman-generator.

NOTE: It would be good if you provide a solution for both LOCALHOST and PRODUCTION.

[image]

My Package.json file is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "homepage": "/plan" must be work, I doubt you've placed it at wrong place, Try again and if won't work out, than please share a screenshot of your package.json

Comment: it runs on "http://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" by default. "http://localhost:3000/plan/taskpane.html" not working

Comment: {
  "name": "office-addin-taskpane-react-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "/plan",
}
@MaulikPatel

Comment: @MaulikPatel images added